# создать варианты и вывести в виде списка

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Всем привет. Такой вопрос. Сразу прошу прощения, так как я мало смыслю в PHP, но знаю что это всего несколько строчек кода. Так вот у меня есть простейшая админка, сделал по урокам в Youtube. Админка самая простая, чистый лист и пару кнопок. Есть база данных. Как мне в админке создать 3 поля с вариантами цветов, например: Синий, желтый, красный, заполнить их в админке, и вывести на сайте в виде выпадающего списка, при этом чтобы выбор снова записывался в базу, но в другую таблицу? В HTML я думаю это будет так:

```html
<select>
<option value="yellow">Желтый</option>
<option value="blue">Синий</option>
<option value="red">Красный</option>
</select>
```

Помогите люди добрые! Всем добра)

Answer (score 1):

Получаем из БД список цветов и текущий цвет

```
$colors=array('Синий','Красный','Желтый');
$current_color = 'Желтый';
// Обработка отправки формы по нажатию на submit
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['color'])){
    $color=$_POST['color'];
    //Далее запись в БД, куда нужно, Хоть прямым запросом хоть используя ORM            
}
```

В виде пишем

```
<?if (isset($colors)):?>
  <select name='color'>
  <?foreach($colors as $color):?>
    <option value="<?=$color?>"
       <?=$color==$current_color?'selected="selected"':''?>>
       <?=$color?>
    </option>
    <?endforeach?>  
  </select>
<?endif?>
```

Как-то так, хотя если цвета хранятся в виде справочника то лучше в option value= писать id цвета. Ну и его же обрабатывать и записывать как текущий цвет.